# Different filename on localhost testserver

Tags: localhost, dreamweaver, filenames

Previewing my webpage the browser URL shows a different file name. For example :
index.php >>> preview in browser localhost/mywebsitename/TMPZB7YOG.php
So there is TMPZB7YOG instead of index ????
How to get to use the filename ?
I am working in MAC OSX 10.9 Mavericks - Dreamweaver CS6 creative cloud

Comment: Could you provide some more information. Where does this file come from? Is it dreamweaver that generates this? Is it your server that generates this?

Comment: Yes, could you please step back and add some more information?  You say you are "previewing".  Could you describe what you have before you "preview", and what steps you take to "preview"?  Even better, add some screenshots for that process! :)

Comment: More info:file is made in dreamweaver, saved as php. Url for test is set http://localhost/mywebsite/. In dreamweaver, I click on preview in browser. Choose Mozilla or safari. Browser opens and I see page but url shows a different file name. Like a random filename with letters and nummers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you need to go into preferences->Preview in browser and UN-check the preview using temporary file checkbox.  You should be good to go from there.